# Programatically create button with 2+ borders

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to create a button with 2+ borders, as in the image below.
Could anyone point out a direction to do it, without recurring to images?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: the easiest way is having 1 image like that, you could probably add layers with different kind of borders but they would have to have different sizes based on how many borders you want. Still image using the auto stretch is the way to go.

Comment: sub-class your button to add 2 borders through overriding drawRect method

Comment: subclassing the button is probably a cleaner way, but how would the several borders be defined? Also, consider that the button might not be square.

Comment: if it is bit score squre than my reply will be different… , going for clips and bounds like that ... @Joao

Comment: @Spynet - care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@joao,

The following is the core code you can further tune the code as per your need,

## .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OD : UIButton

@end
```

## .m file

```
#import "OD.h"

@implementation OD
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
//    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(2, 2)];

    // Draw the lines.
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width -4, 2)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width -4,rect.size.height-4 )];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(2, rect.size.height-4)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
//    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    aPath.lineWidth = 5;

    [aPath fill];
    [aPath stroke];
    [aPath closePath];

    UIBezierPath *bPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(8, 8)];

    // Draw the lines.
    [bPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width -8, 6)];
    [bPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width -8,rect.size.height-8 )];
    [bPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(8, rect.size.height-8)];
    [bPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(8, 8)];

    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    //    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    bPath.lineWidth = 5;

    [bPath fill];
    [bPath stroke];
    [bPath closePath];

    self.layer.borderWidth = 2;

//    self.layer.
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

To add shadows and border is simple.

1) Add the QuartzCore framework to your target.

2) Import the framework header in the class where you want to add borders and shadows. (Or if you have custom class for the button then you can simple import this framework in that class.)

3) To add the border to the button use this code (where button is an IBOutlet connected with the button in interface):

```
[self.button.layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
[self.button.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

4) To add the shadow to the button use the following code:

```
[self.button.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];
[self.button.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[self.button.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
```

Comment: I guess the person wants to add more than 1 border to the button. Your code can only add a single border..

Comment: That's right. The described problem would be trivial for 1 single border (as with this solution). The issue is doing it with 2+ borders + possibly a shadow (hence, using the shadow to simulate a border is not the way to go).

Answer (score 1):

Other Option:

1. Create a Black color View
2. Create a red color view inside first view
3. Create gray color view smaller than red view inside first view
4. Add button with white background having size smaller than gray view inside first view

Comment: An easy way to go for..else you have to overrider Button's drawrect method. If you have such buttons multiple times then you can create a UIView class which have subviews as I mentioned above, so you have to just use that class instead of follow all above steps again and again

Comment: i need 10 buttons like that then what I can do ? 20 views….

Comment: No, just create one class inheriting UIView and code for all other views and button inside its init method. That way, you can use that custom view through out the application.

Comment: why don't we go with the UIBeizer path ?